# Resetting setTimeout function to prevent an action

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, timeout, settimeout

I may be thinking about this the wrong way. So any guidance would be very useful.

I have an element, then when you click opens up a number of radio buttons. Clicking one of the radio buttons triggers a `setTimeout` of `2300ms` this will add a class `Frequency--closing` to an element `Frequency` which triggers an animation in the css, when the timeout finishes, that component gets removed from the DOM.

I am using the timeout as means to allow an animation before it gets removed from the DOM.

What I am aiming for is when I click a radio button and then click another radio button before the component gets removed from the DOM that the timer resets, so on the 2nd click on it waits another `2300ms` before it gets removed from the DOM.

Below is the component that uses state to dictate whether the element is opened or closed with the `onToggle()` function

```
const SavedSearchBox = ({ modifier, search, loading }) => {
  const [frequencyToggled, setFrequencyToggled] = useState(false);
  const [closeFrequency, setCloseFrequency] = useState(false);
  const timeoutRef = useRef(null);

  const onToggle = () => {
    if (frequencyToggled) {
      setCloseFrequency(true);
      timeoutRef.current = setTimeout(
        () => setFrequencyToggled(!frequencyToggled),
        2300
      );
    } else {
      setCloseFrequency(false);
      setFrequencyToggled(!frequencyToggled);
      clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => () => clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current), []);

  return (
    <div
      className={`SavedSearchBox ${modifier ? modifier : ""} ${
        loading && loading.status ? "SavedSearchBox--loading" : ""
      }`}
    >
      <div className="SavedSearchBox-footer">
        {frequencyToggled ? (
          <Frequency
            closeFrequency={closeFrequency}
            onChange={() => onToggle()}
          />
        ) : (
          <div onClick={() => onToggle()}>Click Here</div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The `onToggle()` function also gets called from the child component `Frequency`. This component also includes the class `Frequency--closing` for the closing animation.

```
const Frequency = props => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(0);

  const inputs = [
    ["Instant Alerts", "Instant"],
    ["Twice Daily Alerts", "Twice"],
    ["Daily Alerts", "Daily"],
    ["Weekly Alerts", "Weekly"],
    ["No Email Alerts", "None"]
  ];
  return (
    <div
      className={`Frequency ${
        props.closeFrequency ? "Frequency--closing" : ""
      }`}
    >
      <div className="Frequency-list">
        {inputs.map(([text, value], i) => (
          <div key={i} className="Frequency-listItem">
            <label className="Frequency-listLabel">
              {text}
              <input
                type="radio"
                checked={value === inputs[active][1]}
                onChange={() => {
                  props.onChange();
                  setActive(i);
                }}
                value={value}
              />
              <span className="Frequency-listRadio" />
            </label>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here are the animations in the case that it is that is perhaps causing this issue

```
.Frequency-listItem {
  animation: enter $Frequency-duration $Frequency-easing backwards;
  transform: translateY(0%);
  transition: transform $Frequency-duration ease;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: center;

  @for $i from 1 through 6 {
    &:nth-of-type(#{$i}) {
      animation-delay: calc(#{$i} * #{$Frequency-delay});
    }
  }
}

.Frequency--closing .Frequency-listItem {
   animation: exit $Frequency-exitDuration $Frequency-easing both 1;
   transform: translateY(100%);
   transition: transform $Frequency-exitDuration ease;

   @for $i from 6*-1 through -1 {
      &:nth-of-type(#{abs($i)}) {
         animation-delay: calc(#{abs($i)} * #{$Frequency-exitDelay} + 2s);
      }
    }
 }

@keyframes enter {
  from {
      opacity: 0;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      max-height: 0;
      transform: scale(.7);
  }
}

@keyframes exit {
   from {
       opacity: 1;
       max-height: 100%;
       transform: scale(1);
   }
   to {
      opacity: 0;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      max-height: 0;
      transform: scale(.7);
  }
 }
```

Here is a [CODESANBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/7kno0n838x) if you wish to test it out

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This seems to work: https://codesandbox.io/s/1v556xj14j (I mostly changed the main file but also removed the `2s` delay from the closing animation.

Comment: @Chris G That worked perfectly thank you. Didn't think about using 2 timeouts!